# HDIV + Spring MVC - getting always Unauthorized Access error HDIV_PARAMETER_DOES_NOT_EXIST

Tags: java, spring-mvc, security, servlets, hdiv

I am using HDIV with Spring MVC based on Spring Java Configuration which I derived from their showcase implementation. The configuration get loaded but when I try to access protected URLs i.e. "/messages/message" I get always Unauthorized Access error HDIV_PARAMETER_DOES_NOT_EXIST. It works when I change the config to exclude the URL from HDIV processing but this of course is not an option

Anybody an idea what I missed?

- [hdiv reference documentation](https://hdivsecurity.com/technical-documentation/doc.html#examples-springmvc)
- [hdiv example showcase configuration code](https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv-spring-mvc-showcase-jc/blob/master/src/main/java/org/hdiv/samples/mvc/config/)

**Logfile error statement**

```
10:04:17.304 [http-nio-8080-exec-22] INFO  org.hdiv.logs.Logger - HDIV_PARAMETER_DOES_NOT_EXIST;/spring-security-example/messages/message;_HDIV_STATE_;;;127.0.0.1;127.0.0.1;megloff;
```

**Java Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableHdivWebSecurity
public class HdivSecurityConfig extends HdivWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(SecurityConfigBuilder builder) {
  }

  @Override
  public void addExclusions(ExclusionRegistry registry) {
    registry.addUrlExclusions("/").method("GET");
    registry.addUrlExclusions("/login");
    registry.addUrlExclusions("/logout");
    registry.addUrlExclusions("/static/.*");
    registry.addParamExclusions("_csrf");  


    //  registry.addUrlExclusions("/messages/.*"); <-- would allow access, but not an option      
  }

  @Override
  public void configureEditableValidation(ValidationConfigurer validationConfigurer) {

    validationConfigurer.addValidation("/messages/.*");
    validationConfigurer.addValidation("/addUser");
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "ch.megloff.spring.security.example.mvc.controller",
    "ch.megloff.spring.security.example.mvc.action",
    "ch.megloff.spring.security.example.repository",
    "ch.megloff.spring.security.example.listener", 
    "ch.megloff.spring.security.example.service"})
public class SpringMVCConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("hdivEditableValidator")
  private Validator hdivEditableValidator;

  @Override
  public Validator getValidator() {
    return hdivEditableValidator;
 }

 ...
}


public class SpringWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { SpringMVCConfiguration.class, SpringHibernateConfig.class, SpringSecurityConfiguration.class, SpringSecurityJDBCConfiguration.class, SpringWebFlowConfig.class, HdivSecurityConfig.class };
}

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { SpringMVCConfiguration.class };
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
   }

   public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(container);

    container.addFilter("ValidatorFilter", ValidatorFilter.class).addMappingForUrlPatterns(
            EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), false, "/*");

    container.addListener(new InitListener());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. HDIV requires that all links get enriched with a "_HDIV_STATE_" parameter in its URL. in order to achieve that you have to use taglib from HDIV and not the original JSTL taglib.

Please refer also to the [reference documentation](https://hdivsecurity.com/technical-documentation/doc.html#installation-jstl) of HDIV regarding JSTL

e.g. in your POM

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hdiv</groupId>
        <artifactId>hdiv-jstl-taglibs-1.2</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hdiv-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

e.g. in your JSP (note the 'www.hdiv.org' in the taglib statement)

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://www.hdiv.org/jsp/jstl/core"%>
   <c:url value="/messages/messages" var="url" />
   <li><a href="${url}">Messages</a></li>`

So you need to render the URL via th `<c:url>` utility tag. This renders then the URL with the required HDIV parameter i.e.

```
localhost:8080/spring-security-example/messages/message?_HDIV_STATE_=26-0-830046F08D66980D1B35F52F2D6677E0
```

another option may be is to use the utility class from HDIV
see class [LinkUrlProcessor](https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv/blob/master/hdiv-core/src/main/java/org/hdiv/urlProcessor/LinkUrlProcessor.java) at the github repository of hdiv

```
LinkUrlProcessor urlProcessor = HDIVUtil.getLinkUrlProcessor(servletContext);
String processUrl = urlProcessor.processUrl(request, "/messages/messages");
```